Why are the efficiencies of the two pytorch writing methods in solving softmax so different?
The problem occurred when I was completing eecs-498-007 A2.
In the method softmax_loss_vectorized,I got a way to vectorize:
def softmax_loss_vectorized(
    W: torch.Tensor, X: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor, reg: float
):
    """
    Softmax loss function, vectorized version.  When you implment the
    regularization over W, please DO NOT multiply the regularization term by 1/2
    (no coefficient).

    Inputs and outputs are the same as softmax_loss_naive.
    """
    num_train = X.shape[0]
    scores = X.mm(W)

    max_scores = torch.max(scores, dim=1, keepdim=True).values
    scores -= max_scores

    # compute exp
    exp_scores = torch.exp(scores)
    sum_exp_scores = exp_scores.sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)

    # softmax
    prob = exp_scores / sum_exp_scores

    # Build a torch mask to select correct classes
    correct_class_prob = prob[torch.arange(num_train), y]
    # compute loss and gradient matrix
    loss = -torch.log(correct_class_prob).sum() 
    loss /= num_train
    loss += reg * torch.sum(W * W)

    dscores = prob
    dscores[torch.arange(len(dscores)), y] -= 1
    dW = X.t().mm(dscores) 
    dW /= num_train
    dW += 2 * reg * W
    return loss, dw


but it only speed up by less than 5 times.
then I got another mothed on github:
exp_scores = scores.exp()
exp_scores_sum_log = sum_exp_scores.log()
# loss:
correct_class_scores = scores[range(num_train), y]
loss = (exp_scores_sum_log - correct_class_scores).sum()
loss /= num_train
# dW:
zeros = torch.zeros((num_train, num_classes), dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda')
zeros[range(num_train), y] = -1
minus_X = zeros.t().mm(X)

dw += minus_X.t()
dw += ((exp_scores / sum_exp_scores.view(-1, 1)).t().mm(X)).t()
dw /= num_train
# regularization ...


My understanding is that method 2 uses more preprocessing, but I can hardly understand The process of solving dW using method 2.
